# How would this creature keep its skeleton "host" in one piece?

Tags: creature-design, fantasy-races

In my fantasy world, which lacks a name currently, there is a race of what looks like a series of interconnected worms or maggots that is known for growing in and around skeletons using its own body to act as the skeletons muscles. Basically using the skeleton as both a shell and transportation (basically my, I think uniquish, skeleton hoard).

Now I'm wondering how would this creature reasonably bind the bones together? Bonus points for a way that would allow fluid motion.

Note: The feasibility of this race will come as a later question.

Comment: *"Now I'm wondering how would this creature reasonably bind the bones together?"* Ever seen a videogame called Octopus Dad? Anyway +1.

Comment: You mean like the [lekgolo](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Lekgolo) in the Halo universe?

Comment: if they are acting like the muscles aren't they bonding the bones together?

Comment: How do the worms coordinate movement? And in response to what stimuli? Without coordination the bag-o-bones would seem to just sit there and quiver and writhe.

Comment: Is this actually a colony of multiple worms or one creature that has the appearance of multiple worms?

Comment: @user535733 I assume they are a bundle of nerves with some sort of main brain probably bidding in the skull th st coordinates them.

Comment: @Joe Bloggs I honestly haven't decided yet I'm leaning towards either one creature or a colony that has some sort of central mind.

Comment: [Reminder to close-voters](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3773/6986): The problem cannot be fixed if the OP is not made aware of it.

Comment: Sorry but if the worms are acting as the muscles of a body that uses the scavenged bones from other creates are they not already holding those bones together? I find it very hard to understand what you're actually asking here.

Comment: @Ash They use the skeletons of creatures as a shell and the colony itself (the worms) act as the muscles of the skeleton (they eat the remaining flesh off of the skeleton) so they can move around.

Comment: @CelestialDragonEmperor Yup, human muscles hold our skeleton together, if the worms are acting as muscles how are they _**not** already_ doing the job you're asking about, and if they are what then is your question?

Comment: @Ash I need a way for the works to not only mimic muscles but still be able to keep the skeletal frame intact. From this people have suggested stuff like special secretions or silk tendons.

Comment: @CelestialDragonEmperor Right I give up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More or less what you find in social insects, where there are the workers, the soldiers and the egg layer, in this species there are different specializations: some individuals are better suited to mimic the muscles, some other the tendons and ligaments, some other the skin. (At the end you don't want them to dry up in a sunny day, don't you?)

They know more or less how to arrange around bones to keep them in place, and then they mimic the organization of tendons and muscles to be able to enact movements.

Comment: Hmm... Well this would be a interesting skeleton indeed especially if the worms are only a thin layer on the skeleton. The image in my head is pretty scary, :P

Answer (score 2):

If the worms claimed recently deceased hosts, they could east up the muscle and other soft tissue and replace them, but keep the tendons, cartilage etc intact. 
This may also deal with the feasibility of how they know how to organise themselves - they just copy the old host.

Comment: I like this one and makes sense seeing as the initial flesh gives them time to feed and grow.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you could use some sort of specialized secretion. I get the impression you want the worms to be fairly small. With that in mind, something like mucuous or silk might work. Seeing as his muscles are normally attached to bone with tendons, you could have these worms use a silk-like material as a substitute for tendons. I suggest picking a natural base like one of these and tweak it to suit your needs.

(P.S. This is my first answer, so apologies if I missed any bits of etiquette.)

Comment: I currently don't know about size, but silk like substance does sound good. Also no worries this was a good and we'll thought out answer (I'm newish too so no worries).

Answer (score 1):

You could say that the worms or maggots produce a gooey sticky slime which acts as an adhesive to bones. not only will it be bonded strongly but also will be very flexible. As for the control, there can be a main queen worm which acts like the head and is responsible for just control, while other worms take care of the other functions or you can even have a certain kind of neural signals with a feedback which can transmit over their skins, helping them in coordination and control.

Comment: Yeah I had the idea of a queen worm that would control the host. Honestly she could probably just hide in the skull.